# Subtraction doesn't work in do while how can I fix it?

Tags: c

Hi I am new in c and I making a text adventure game. But I have a problem withe subtraction in a do while loop. The problem is that the number doesn't change it remains at 95 or in 90 in the second statement. Can someone help how to fix that and explain to me how subtraction works in a loop? Also, I want the loop end when the enemy's life is at zero

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
struct batman{
    int helath,punch,kick,darts;
};

int main(void) {
    int s=0,sum=0,r,knife=5,gun1=10,punch,enemy=100;

    struct batman b;

    b.helath=100;
    b.punch=5;
    b.kick=10;
    b.darts=100;

    printf("\nPress 1 for punch and 2 for kick");

    srand(time(NULL));
    do{
        scanf("%d",&punch);
        if(punch==1){
            sum=b.punch-enemy;
            printf("\nEnemy's Helath %d",sum);
        }
        else if(punch==2){
            sum=b.kick-enemy;
            printf("\nEnemy's Helath %d",sum);
        }
        r=rand()%2;
        if(r==1){
            s=b.helath-knife;
            printf("\nBatman's Health%d",s);

        }
        else if(r==2){
            s=b.helath-gun1;
            printf("\nBatman's Health%d",s);

        }

    }while(punch==1||punch>=2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Format your code and explain your problem please

Comment: You will have to assign new values to variables you want to update.

Comment: "The problem is that the number doesn't change it remains at 95 or in 90 in the second statement." Which number doesn't change? What is "the second statement"?

Comment: `while (punch ==1 || punch >= 2)` why not `while (punch >= 1)`?

Comment: Each time you assign to `sum` you're not subtracting from the old `sum`. You're just subtracting from the value in `b`, which doesn't change.

Comment: I think what you really want is `enemy = enemy - b.punch;`

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 2):

The value of enemy never changes, so unless the value of punch changes this is effectively a constant. You probably want to do something like:

```
enemy -= punch;
if (enemy <= 0) {
  printf("Batman wins!");
}
```

to update the health of the enemy. For batman you probably want to do the same, i.e.,

```
b.health -= gun;
if (b.health <= 0) {
  printf("Oh no! Batman lost.");
} else {
  printf("Batman's health: %d", b.health);
}
```

Your game should probably end when either batman.health or enemy reaches 0, so you would want to add a check.